# TaskManager class design

Tags: design, architecture, object-oriented-design

We implemented a TaskManager class for this purpose: execute a number of tasks asynchronously (off the UI thread) one after the other. Basically, this class includes a queue of tasks and the functions to run/execute them.

Considering that the class is a hybrid between a collection and a manager, the question is: Should we have a separate queue inside it or not? What is the best architecture in this scenario?

```
public class TaskManager
{
    public List<Task> Queue; 

    public Exexcute(Task t) {...}
    public ExexcuteAll() {...}
}
```

or

```
public class TaskManager
{
    private List<Task> _queue; 

    public AppendToQueue() {...}
    public RemoveFromQueue() {...}

    public Execute(Task t) {...}
    public ExecuteAll() {...}
}
```

**EDIT**: We are not interested in suggestions on how to code this but on class architecture/design only. Thanks.

Comment: The "best" is probably using a normal ExecutorService instead. OK, it does not have a "remove", but you could flag this inside your callables instead.

Comment: @mtj I think the question is related to design-pattern and not about an alternative object to use :)

Comment: @ilCosmico The question seems about a very specific case, which looks like reinventing the wheel. As esp. SE has a strong focus on real world problems in real world projects, I only point out the old rule, that normally the best software is the one that you don't have to write. (There's exceptions to the rule, but you have to look very carefully.)

Comment: @mtj Agree with you. Maybe this is a simplified example of the goal, but now I better understand your answer.

Comment: "asynchronously one after the other" is a contradiction. If you're doing them one after the other, they're not being done asynchronously.

Comment: @abenci Is thread-safety part of the consideration? If so, may I ask why `List<Task>` is preferred over `ConcurrentQueue<Action>` [(MSDN doc)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0)? If thread-safety is not part of consideration, what value does `TaskManager` provide, other than merely being an `IEnumerable<Action>` ?

Comment: "asynchronously" in this case only seems to mean "not blocking the UI Thread". Also you can do "async" programming which is executed single threaded (see nodejs). Asynchronously does not automatically imply parallel execution.

Comment: Bottom line: if the queue has items submitted from one thread, and items consumed from a different thread, `Queue` or `List` is definitely the wrong class to use. `BlockingCollection` is the correct one to use. (Underlying it uses `ConcurrentQueue`, but the former provides a crucial enhancement.) Aside from a basic guarantee of thread safety, it also provides a few capabilities that enhances its use as a channel of tasks between submitting threads and executing threads. An example of such essential enhancement is `BlockingCollection.CompleteAdding` method.

Comment: The difference in code is only about encapsulating the list. Encapsulation is good. Why shouldn’t it be encapsulated?

Comment: Can you design the interface without talking about a queue at all?

Comment: A typical cross-thread executor consists of three facets. (1) submitter side, which allows packaged tasks to be submitted (2) execution side, where one or more threads will dequeue individual packaged tasks for execution (3) management side, where high-level parameters such as degree of parallelism, thread spawning and idle thread timeout shutdown options can be configured. These facets belong to the executor, and may be implemented as a single class or several classes. A package task has several facets of its own, such as a handle to an executable function, inputs, results, and ...

Comment: I'm not seeing producer and consumer in this example, so not sure if queue is necessary in this class, executor service is probably sufficient. And if there are producer/consumer, they should be separate services that handles queue writing and message picking up

Comment: What are the semantics of task completion? For example: Will another thread need to wait for completion of some/all tasks? Will each task update state somewhere to indicate its completion? Is there a notion of task failure? Will some tasks depend on other tasks? One related design pattern is *futures*.